# JMeter XPath query not finding required value

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I am getting the following response from JMeter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CertificateResponse>
    <certificates>
        <certificate>
            <amount>
                <value>100.00</value>
            </amount>
            <appleRetail>false</appleRetail>
            <attributes>
                <entry key="XYZ">444</entry>
                <entry key="ABC">DEF</entry>
            </attributes>
            <cardType>1</cardType>
            <datePurchased>06/13/2013 12:47:04:000 GMT</datePurchased>
            <id>XWGL6GMXWN3P8TXL</id>
            <lineItemNumber>1</lineItemNumber>
            <purchaserDSIDLong>12860</purchaserDSIDLong>
            <refID>XCard_0000250410356</refID>
            <salesOrgId>
                <description>US</description>
                <ID>1</ID>
            </salesOrgId>
            <status>2</status>
            <supportDSID>0</supportDSID>
            <variableCard>false</variableCard>
            <webOrderNumber>M33764265</webOrderNumber>
        </certificate>
    </certificates>
</CertificateResponse>
```

I am using the following XPath query in HTTP Sampler in JMeter, I'm not ale to to retrieve the value.

```
/CertificateResponse/certificates/certificate/id
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In future please take the time to correctly format any data in your question before you post it. (Otherwise people will simply ignore it - why should they spend the time when you couldn't be bothered to after all.)

Comment: Your XPath is fine, the problem must be in the code calling the XPath expression, post more code. Is this exactly the XML input you're working with (eg., are namespaces included)?

Answer (score 1):

> I am using the following XPath query in HTTP Sampler in JMeter...

Your XPath expression works fine but you have to use it along with [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) attached to the sampler that returns xml response:

[image]

```
Use Tidy (tolerant parser): No

Reference Name: certificateID
XPath Query: //CertificateResponse/certificates/certificate/id
Default Value: NOT_FOUND
```

This will extract value of `id` into jmeter variable `certificateID` which you can than refer as `${certificateID}`.